# Generate invoice based on transactions and put invoice number in transaction column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**The case**

Hello, I'm building a Customer Loyality System where customers can use a personal loyality card to earn points and buy articles with this points.
Generally, we deal with three parties:

- Loyality provider (manages the cashflow in the whole system)
- Shop (-owners / -employees) (can sell or give away points to the customers or take points from customers)
- Customer (can earn or buy points / buy products with earned or buyed points)

Every week the provider needs to generate invoices per shop for a period given based on open transactions.

100 points equals € 1,-, so basically every euro cent (€ 0,01) is one point in our system.

So lets say, a shop employee sells € 10,- of points (1000 points) to a customer, this will generate the following transaction:

```
| RecordId | Description | Credit | Debit | State | CreationDate ... CardId | LocationId | InvoiceId |
| (ID)     | (Descr.)    | 1000   | 0     | Open  | ...                     | 10001      | NULL      |
```

Now, the customer buys a product of € 3,-.
This will generate the following transaction:

```
| RecordId | Description | Credit | Debit | State | CreationDate ... CardId | LocationId | InvoiceId |
| (ID)     | (Descr.)    | 0      | 300   | Open  | ...                     | 10001      | NULL      |
```

Later that week, the same customer will also buy antoher product for € 2,- at the same shop.
This will generate the following transaction:

```
| RecordId | Description | Credit | Debit | State | CreationDate ... CardId | LocationId | InvoiceId |
| (ID)     | (Descr.)    | 0      | 200   | Open  | ...                     | 10001      | NULL      |
```

Another client buys € 25,- of points (2500 points)
This generates the following transaction:

```
| RecordId | Description | Credit | Debit | State | CreationDate ... CardId | LocationId | InvoiceId |
| (ID)     | (Descr.)    | 2500   | 0     | Open  | ...                     | 10001      | NULL      |
```

This customer buys a product of € 4,- (400 points)
This generates the following transaction:

```
| RecordId | Description | Credit | Debit | State | CreationDate ... CardId | LocationId | InvoiceId |
| (ID)     | (Descr.)    | 0      | 400   | Open  | ...                     | 10001      | NULL      |
```

So the shop owner needs to pay (1000 - (300 + 200) = 500) + ((2500 - 400) - 2100)  = 26 euros to the provider.

---

**Invoicing**

The shop employee should receive an invoice at the end of the week with the following data

```
Period Invoice - Week X

Period Start:  dd-mm-yyyy
Period End:  dd-mm-yyyy

Points sold: 3500
Points collected: 900
------------------------ -
Total: 2600

To pay: € 26,-
```

There are situations possible where shop owners only get money, the invoice will be negative in that case.

---

**The Database**

Well, i will only describe the tables needed for this query.

*Invoices*

```
[RecordId] [int] IDENTITY(10001,1) NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ToPay] [int] NOT NULL,
[ToReceive] [int] NOT NULL,
[Total] [int] NOT NULL,
[PeriodStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[PeriodEnd] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[State] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[PaidDate] [datetime] NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DeletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LocationId] [int] NOT NULL
```

*Transactions*

```
[RecordId] [int] IDENTITY(10001,1) NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Credit] [int] NOT NULL,
[Debit] [int] NOT NULL,
[State] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DeletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
[EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CardId] [int] NOT NULL,
[LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
[InvoiceId] [int] NOT NULL
```

---

**The query** (so far)

Is was able to write (ehm, copy) a StoredProcedure to get all open transactions for a specific period:

```
INSERT INTO [Invoices] ([Description], [ToPay], [ToReceive], [Total], [PeriodStart], [PeriodEnd], [LocationId])
SELECT
@Description AS [Description],
SUM([Credit]) AS [ToPay],
    SUM([Debit]) AS [ToReceive],
    SUM([Credit]) - SUM([Debit]) AS [Total],
    @PeriodStart AS [PeriodStart],
    @PeriodEnd AS [PeriodEnd],
    [LocationId]
FROM
    [Transactions]
WHERE
    [State] = 'Open' AND
    [CreatedDate] BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PeriodEnd
GROUP BY [LocationId]
```

The select gives the following result:

```
| ToPay | ToReceive | Total | PeriodStart | PeriodEnd | LocationId |
| 3500  | 900       | 2600  | (Start)     | (End)     | 10001      |
```

And will be inserted into the [Invoices] table.

---

**The question**

By using the query above, every location (shop) gets it's own record for the period given.
So, every location gets an invoice record in the [Invoices] table.

The [RecordId] column increments one by every insert (identity)

This is where i'm stuck:
After every record creation, its [RecordID] needs to be written to the [Transactions] table (in the [InvoiceId] column) at the records used to generate the new record in the [Invoices] table, also the [State] column of the transactions needs te be changed from 'Open' to 'Invoice'

I'm aware of the ability to get the Recordid of the latest record with

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

---

**The result** (as it should be)

When a shop owner requests his/her invoice details, the transactions can be resolved by selecting al transactions by InvoiceId:

```
SELECT * FROM [Transactions] WHERE [InvoiceId] = @InvoiceId
```

---

**Additional information**

The system is runnng MSSQL 2008 and the front end is running MS MVC3 (C#).

**UPDATE**: I had to change my datamodel a bit.

P.S. Appologies for my (not so gooed) English.

**Update**

OK, I fixed it by adding

```
UPDATE [Transactions] SET
[Transactions].[State] = 'Invoice',
[Transactions].[InvoiceId] = [Invoices].[RecordId]
FROM
[Transactions]
INNER JOIN
[Invoices]
ON
[Transactions].[CreatedDate] BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PeriodEnd
```

But I think this is just a hack and not the way to do this.
The reason i think this is not right is, can someting change in the tables (lets say a transaction is added) between the two queries? thei're both in the same Stored Procedure.
For now this is ok, cause the transactions are parsed ad midnight, when shops are closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it by adding

```
UPDATE [Transactions] SET
    [Transactions].[State] = 'Invoice',
    [Transactions].[InvoiceId] = [Invoices].[RecordId]
FROM
    [Transactions]
INNER JOIN
    [Invoices]
ON
    [Transactions].[CreatedDate] BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PeriodEnd
```

But I think this is just a hack and not the way to do this. The reason i think this is not right is, can someting change in the tables (lets say a transaction is added) between the two queries? thei're both in the same Stored Procedure. For now this is ok, cause the transactions are parsed ad midnight, when shops are closed.